# Задержка отображения графики в многопоточном приложении на Java FX

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx, графика

Решил написать игрушку на java, графику реализовал при помощи api - java fx (смысл в том, что в игре есть некоторое количество стран, для каждой страны выделяется поток, и они при помощи спец. методов пытаются друг друга уничтожить, при этом игра разделена на ходы, и за 1 ход каждая страна может походить только 1 раз, игра заканчивается, когда остается 1 страна - она и считается победителем). Логику написал, пытаюсь присобачить ее к графике, что бы она динамически изменялась по ходу выполнения программы (на игровую консоль выводились результаты битв, страны на игровой карте перекрашивались в цвета победителей  и т.д.), но вот тут то как раз и возникла проблемма - при запуске игры она какое то время думает (примерно 2-3 сек) и выдает сразу результат всех ходов в игровом окне, а также уже полностью закрашеную в цвет победителя карту. А нужно, что бы окно игры изменялось динамически, по ходу работы программы. Я много чего перепробовал, но так и не нашел результата, я даже не до конца могу понять в чем тут ошибка, прикладываю код:

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.effect.ColorAdjust;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.Phaser;

public class MultiMain {
    @FXML
    TextArea display;

    @FXML
    ImageView Portugal;
    @FXML
    ImageView Spain;
    @FXML
    ImageView France;
    @FXML
    ImageView Germany;
    @FXML
    ImageView Switzeland;
    @FXML
    ImageView Italy;


    Phaser phaser;
    CommonResource res;
    int phase;


    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        setColorPortugal(0.1); // изменение цветового диапазона карт в игре
        setColorSpain(0.2);
        setColorFrance(0.3);
        setColorGermany(0.4);
        setColorSwitzeland(0.5);
        setColorItaly(0.6);
    }

    public void setDisplay(String msg) {
        display.setText(display.getText() + "\n" + msg);
    }

    
    public void setColorItaly(Double hue) {
        ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
        colorAdjust.setHue(hue);
        Italy.setEffect(colorAdjust);
    }

    public void setColorSpain(Double hue) {
        ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
        colorAdjust.setHue(hue);
        Spain.setEffect(colorAdjust);
    }

    public void setColorPortugal(Double hue) {
        ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
        colorAdjust.setHue(hue);
        Portugal.setEffect(colorAdjust);
    }

    public void setColorFrance(Double hue) {
        ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
        colorAdjust.setHue(hue);
        France.setEffect(colorAdjust);
    }

    public void setColorSwitzeland(Double hue) {
        ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
        colorAdjust.setHue(hue);
        Switzeland.setEffect(colorAdjust);
    }

    public void setColorGermany(Double hue) {
        ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
        colorAdjust.setHue(hue);
        Germany.setEffect(colorAdjust);
    }

    public void actionStart() {

        phaser = new Phaser(1);
        res = new CommonResource();
        int somebodyWon;
        boolean stop = false;
        new Thread(new CountryThread(res, "Portugal", new Country("Portugal", 1, 1, 8, 8, 0.1))).start();
        //setColorPortugal(0.1);
        new Thread(new CountryThread(res, "Spain", new Country("Spain", 1, 2, 8, 9, 0.2))).start();
        //setColorSpain(0.2);
        new Thread(new CountryThread(res, "France", new Country("France", 2, 1, 3, 4, 0.3))).start();
        //setColorFrance(0.3);
        new Thread(new CountryThread(res, "Germany", new Country("Germany", 2, 2, 9, 7, 0.4))).start();
        //setColorGermany(0.4);
        new Thread(new CountryThread(res, "Switzeland", new Country("Switzeland", 1, 3, 3, 4, 0.5))).start();
        //setColorSwitzeland(0.5);
        new Thread(new CountryThread(res, "Italy", new Country("Italy", 2, 3, 5, 6, 0.6))).start();
        //setColorItaly(0.6);

        while (!stop) {

            somebodyWon = res.names.size();

            if (somebodyWon != 1) {
                // ждем завершения фазы
                phase = phaser.getPhase();
                phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Ход " + phase + " завершен");
                System.out.println("Выжили: " + res.printWhoAlive());
                System.out.println(" ");

                setDisplay("Ход " + phase + " завершен"); // вывод на дисплей игры
                setDisplay("Выжили: " + res.printWhoAlive());

            } else {
                phaser.arriveAndDeregister(); // сообщаем о завершении фаз и удаляем с регистрации объекты
                stop = true;
                //return;
            }
        }
    }


    class CountryThread extends Task {

        String name;
        CommonResource res;
        Country country;

        CountryThread(CommonResource res, String n, Country country) {

            this.name = n;
            this.res = res;
            this.country = country;
            phaser.register();

        }


        public void runSmth() {
        /*Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {*/
            int somebodyWon;
            boolean stop = false;

            while (!stop) {

                somebodyWon = res.names.size();

                if (somebodyWon != 1) {
                    res.attack(name);
                    phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance(); // сообщаем, что первая фаза достигнута
                } else {
                    phaser.arriveAndDeregister(); // сообщаем о завершении фаз и удаляем с регистрации объекты
                    stop = true;
                    //return;
                }
            }

            /*}
        });*/

        }

        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            runSmth();
            return 1;
        }
    }

    class CommonResource {


        ArrayList<Country> names = new ArrayList<>();

        CommonResource() {
            names.add(new Country("Portugal", 1, 1, 8, 8, 0.1));
            names.add(new Country("Spain", 1, 2, 8, 9, 0.2));
            names.add(new Country("France", 2, 1, 3, 4, 0.3));
            names.add(new Country("Germany", 2, 2, 9, 7, 0.4));
            names.add(new Country("Switzeland", 1, 3, 3, 4, 0.5));
            names.add(new Country("Italy", 2, 3, 5, 6, 0.6));

        }

        public String printWhoAlive() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
                sb.append(names.get(i).getName());
                sb.append("; ");
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        synchronized void attack(String name) { // метод атаки (логика)
            try {
                String ownName = name;
                int ownIndex = -1;
                for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
                    if (names.get(i).getName().equals(ownName)) {
                        ownIndex = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (ownIndex != -1) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
                        if (i != ownIndex) {
                            System.out.println("собственное имя " + names.get(ownIndex).getName() + " просматривает " + names.get(i).getName());

                            if (names.get(ownIndex).isNeighbor(names.get(i))) {
                                boolean IWon = names.get(ownIndex).Attack(names.get(i));
                                if (IWon) {
                                    for (int j = 0; j < names.get(i).getiOwn().size(); j++) {
                                        names.get(ownIndex).setiOwn(names.get(i).getiOwn().get(j));
                                    }
                                    names.get(ownIndex).setiOwn(names.get(i).getName());
                                    for (int j = 0; j < names.get(ownIndex).getiOwn().size(); j++) {
                                        switch (names.get(ownIndex).getiOwn().get(j)) {
                                            case "Portugal":
                                                setColorPortugal(names.get(ownIndex).getHue());
                                                break;
                                            case "Spain":
                                                setColorSpain(names.get(ownIndex).getHue());
                                                break;
                                            case "France":
                                                setColorFrance(names.get(ownIndex).getHue());
                                                break;
                                            case "Germany":
                                                setColorGermany(names.get(ownIndex).getHue());
                                                break;
                                            case "Switzeland":
                                                setColorSwitzeland(names.get(ownIndex).getHue());
                                                break;
                                            case "Italy":
                                                setColorItaly(names.get(ownIndex).getHue());
                                                break;

                                            default: {
                                                System.out.println("error while try to chanhe color");
                                                break;
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }

                                    names.remove(names.get(i));
                                    try {
                                        Thread.sleep(500);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                                return;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                } else {

                    //Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.

P.S. - вид окна
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подозреваю, что методы setColor* должны вызываться в fx application thread, нужно обернуть в Platform.runLater( () -> setColor*)

Comment: пробовал - все тоже самое, перекраска карты и вывод результатов в TextArea в конце игры, динамически не хочет делать(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем переписал программу заново без использование phasera и все заработало